# Rename column in entity framework

Tags: entity-framework-4

I have a table 'UserLogin' which contains the columns: `id` and `userid`. Suppose I want to show `userid` as 'user' in Gridview then we write query in sql

```
select userid as user from UserLogin
```

But I am working with entity framework. How can we solve this problem in entity framework?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually you specify different Header text for that column within your GridView control.

But you can achieve similar functionality in Entity framework by using

```
select new { user = UserLogin.userid, id = UserLogin.id };
```